# My cobol string will not allow me to break it apart?

Tags: cobol

How in Cobol do I break a literal apart on each line to write back to the screen or a file?

Code:

```
   05 CONSTPARM             PIC X(78) VALUE             
   'SW89JSXX PROV RANGE 01: XXXXXXX THRU XXXXXXX   ' 
   -      'TAXONOMY: XXXXXXXXXX'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have actual strings in COBOL. Fields are just as long as they are defined as.

However, if you want to "break something", we have a verb called UNSTRING:

```
UNSTRING CONSTPARM INTO xxxx DELIMITED BY ALL SPACE
                        yyyy DELIMITED BY ALL SPACE
                        zzzz DELIMITED BY ALL SPACE
                        lackofforethought DELIMITED BY ALL SPACE
                        etc
```

You have to name the fields you want to receive the data.

If using the same `UNSTRING` more than once, *before* doing the `UNSTRING` set all the target fields to initial values. Otherwise can get data "left over" from the previous use of that `UNSTRING`.

For a full explanation, consult your manual. Enterprise COBOL Language Reference. `UNSTRING` is very powerful, and has lots of options.

To put a field together (or to wrap a Christmas present) use `STRING`.

Comment: What if I want to continue the line of cobol to the next line.

Comment: No problem. Just write on the next line. The only thing which needs a continuation marker in column seven is a literal, like you've got. And those you can define with smaller individual `FILLER`s so you never have to use the continuation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **reference modification**?  Reference modification resembles the use of substringing from many other languages.  It can be used to select segments of another data item by providing a place to start from and the number of characters to bring back.  The referenced field remains unchanged.

```
05 CONSTPARM             PIC X(78) VALUE             
'SW89JSXX PROV RANGE 01: XXXXXXX THRU XXXXXXX   ' 
-      'TAXONOMY: XXXXXXXXXX'.                   
05 WS-FIRST-FOUR         PIC X(5).
05 WS-RANGE              PIC X(5).

MOVE CONSTPARM(1:4)  TO WS-FIRST-FOUR.    
MOVE CONSTPARM(15:5) TO WS-RANGE.

DISPLAY 'WS-FIRST-FOUR = ' WS-FIRST-FOUR.    
DISPLAY 'WS-RANGE = ' WS-RANGE.
```

Your value in **WS-FIRST-FOUR** would be '**SW89**' and your value in **WS-RANGE** would be '**RANGE**'.

For another example and more details, you can visit this helpful guide: http://www.fluffycat.com/COBOL/Reference-Modification/

Comment: The question is "how to break the string". If you are going to suggest reference-modification, shouldn't your sample code show how to do that, rather than just show it exits (which @user3376708 already knows). Or are you just plugging that web site?